# Azure Function Python Environment Variables

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

I hope somebody can help to clarify this issue.
I have an azure function running some python code. The function itself is pretty simple, as I just need to loop over resource groups and list all the storage accounts inside each resource group.

Locally as python code is running just fine and I can access the resources with my service principle.

So I decided to automate this in an azure function as follow:

```
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    KeyVault_Url = f'KeyVault connection String'
    
    
    client_keyvault = SecretClient(vault_url=KeyVault_Url, credential=credentials)
    subscription_id = client_keyvault.get_secret("subscribed").value
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    logging.info('This should run')

    for resource_group in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
        logging.info(resource_group.name)
        for storage in storage_client.storage_accounts.list_by_resource_group(resource_group.name):
            logging.info(f"Storage Account is: {storage.name}")
            print(f"\tStorage Account: {storage.name}")
```

When I trigger manually this function, it run successfully but in the logs, I don't see the last 2 line of code. it seems that the `forloop` is not reached.

I checked the output of the function, and I found bizarre this:

```
Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription/resourcegroups?api-version=REDACTED' Request method: 'GET' Request headers: 'Accept': 'application/json' 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'id' 'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-azure-mgmt-resource/21.1.0 Python/3.9.12 (Linux-5.4.81-microsoft-standard-x86_64-with-glibc2.31)' 'Authorization': 'REDACTED' No body was attached to the request
```

The redacted is not really clear to me what it means and if that is the cause why the `for loop` is not running.

Here is my question to overcome this.
I have a service principle that has the right permission to run this task, and I would like to configure this credential in a json file in the function project, so after the deployment I can just set those variables in the configuration blade of the azure function itself.

At the root folder of the project I have a file called `local.settings.json` with a set of configuration to run the function locally. And as far as I know in c# you can have a `upsetting.[environemt].json` and you can configure specific variables to be used in specific environments. Can anyone help understand how to solve this?

Basically I want to have `appsettings.staging.json` file with specific variables, like:

```
client_id: "client_id"
tenant_id: "tenant_id"
```

and set the values in the azure function configuration in the portal.

Is there a way to do this in python function?

I hope I explained my problem well, and please if I didn't do not hesitate to ask more details.

Thank you so much for any help or hint that you can provide me with.

Answer (score 0):

We use Azure Keyvault to store the environment-specific variables and query based on each Environment.

```
{
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID": "***",
    "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "***",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "***",
}
```